# How do you add another group admin in Skype?

Tags: skype, skype-for-windows-10

I created a Skype group but now I want to add another person as admin. How can I do that?

Comment: How did you create it, what process did you follow, and what do you see options wise available that may be applicable for the task?

Answer (score 0):

In the group chat run the following command:

```
/setrole <username> MASTER
```

Instead of MASTER you can also use ADMIN.

To find a username you can use the command:

```
/showmembers
```